# Cauchy-Schwarz matrix inequality for random vectors

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, inequality

If $X$ and $Y$ are random scalars, then Cauchy-Schwarz says that
$$| \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) | \le \mathrm{Var}(X)^{1/2}\mathrm{Var}(Y)^{1/2}.$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors, is there a way to bound the covariance matrix $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ in terms of the matrices $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$?

In particular, is it true that
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \le \mathrm{Var}(X)^{1/2}\mathrm{Var}(Y)^{1/2},$$
where the square roots are Cholesky decompositions, and the inequality is read as meaning that the right hand side minus the left hand side is positive semidefinite?

Comment: The variance "matrix" is actually a vector (or a matrix consisting of a single row or a single column if you prefer. So you probably want to state the product on the right in slightly different fashion, using transposes etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - $Var(X)$ is a square $nxn$ matrix, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$.

Comment: Thee are $n$ random variables and so $n$ variances. Could you specify what the $n^2$ elements of $\text{var}(X)$ are? Maybe you meant the covariance matrix of the $n$ random variables?

Comment: Sorry if this notation was unclear, I did indeed mean the $nxn$ matrix which has $(i,j)^{th}$ element $Cov(X_i,X_j)$.

Comment: Got something from my answer below?

Answer (score 6):

There is a generalization of Cauchy Schwarz inequality from Tripathi [1] that says that:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Var}(Y) \ge \mathrm{Cov}(Y,X)\mathrm{Var}(X)^{-1}\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)
\end{equation}
in the sense that the diference is semidefinite positive.
He actually says that a student asked about it and couldn't find any other reference (1998!).

[1]: G. Tripathi, ”A matrix extension of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality”, Economics Letters, vol. 63, nr 1, s. 1–3, apr. 1999, doi: 10.1016/S0165-1765(99)00014-2.

Comment: @Did Would this inequality hold if you had $ \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \le \mathrm{Var}(X)^{1/2} (\mathrm{Var}(Y)^{1/2})^t$ please notice the transpose after the  $\mathrm{Var}(Y)^{1/2}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631994/cauchy-schwarz-inequality-for-random-vectors

Comment: When equality holds?

Comment: @Planche see Remark 1.1 in the paper. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176599000142

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $X=Y$ has variance matrix $LL^T$. Then one asks whether $|x^*Cx|\leqslant x^*L^2x$ for every deterministic vector $x$, with $C=LL^T$. This cannot hold. A specific counterexample valid in every dimension at least 2 is when $L_{ij}=1$ if $j=1$ and $L_{ij}=0$ otherwise.  Equivalently, $C_{ij}=1$ for every $(i,j)$, that is, $X_i=X_0$ for every $i$, for some standard normal $X_0$.